# Правильное строение цикла для красивого progress bar

Tags: python, циклы, progress-bar

Хочу использовать progress bar, который рисует в таком формате: `X/Y`, где `X` - текущая итерация, `Y` - последняя итерация. Цикл должен работать от начальной до конечной итерации включительно.

Например, если `X = 1`, `Y = 5`, то должно выводится: `1/5 -> 2/5 -> 3/5 -> 4/5 -> 5/5` (без 0 и 6, т.е. не сколько выполнено, а на какой итерации мы сейчас).

Пробую так:

```
import contextlib
import time

import tqdm

start = 1
end = 5
cur = start
condition = start <= end

with contextlib.closing(tqdm.tqdm(initial=start, total=end)) as progress_bar:
    while condition:
        time.sleep(1)

        cur += 1
        progress_bar.update()
        condition = cur <= end
```

Однако после `5/5` он из-за лишнего апдейта рисует `6` и останавливается. Можно как-то избежать этого последнего `6` без двойной проверки в цикле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вроде нормально отрабатывает:

```
cur += 1
condition = cur <= end
if condition:
    progress_bar.update()
```

Получается, что `update` на последней итерации цикла уже лишний (именно он выставляет и отображает значение `6`), его надо как-то исключить.

Можно чуть сократить код, если вспомнить, что True = 1, False = 0:

```
cur += 1
condition = cur <= end
progress_bar.update(condition)
```

Вариант без двойной проверки условия:

```
with contextlib.closing(tqdm.tqdm(initial=start, total=end)) as progress_bar:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

        cur += 1
        if cur > end:
            break
            
        progress_bar.update()
```

Comment: Хм, а во втором варианте лишней проверки нет получается? Или преобразование `condition` в `int` равносильно этой проверке?

Comment: @ubuntu Добавил вариант с прямо точно одной проверкой )

Comment: Всё равно интересно, отличаются ли первый и второй варианты по количеству проверок, т.е. делает ли питон проверку при преобразовании в `int`

Comment: @ubuntu Ну нет, там уже результат в переменной лежит. Другое дело, что у вас до цикла была ещё одна проверка, это вот не очень красиво выглядит :)

Comment: Как ни мерял, по времени 1 и 2 варианты не отличаются. Хотя там упор в отрисовку `progress_bar`, наверное

Comment: @ubuntu Конечно. Проверок условия типа `число < число` туда хоть миллион можно напихать, это очень быстро происходит. А вот отрисовка индикатора `tqdm` - это действительно то, что ест существенно времени. В основном из-за вывода на консоль. Я в каких-то задачах вообще вынужден был убирать `tqdm`, потому что на миллионах итераций тормоза были уже существенные.

Answer (score 1):

Лишнего чего-то навертели...

```
while cur <= end:
    time.sleep(1)
    progress_bar.update()
    cur += 1
```

Comment: `6it` осталось всё равно